# Dirt cheap 3-12v DC/DC isolatior chip?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, isolation

I'm creating a box that will have an external TTL trigger. I want to isolate my box's power/ground from that of the triggering device.
Obviously, an optoisolator is the way to go (eg. PS2502).

HOWEVER...
I want to offer V+ and GND as well as the Opto's anode/cathode so that an unpowered device (eg. a dumb toggle switch) can run the trigger in addition to powered devices (which can src the current to turn on the opto). I'' build a series resistor into the exposed V+ so the opto can be direct-connected with no worries.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTFat6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Of course, in the above ckt I don't really need isolation.

BUT, when an external, powered device is used to drive the opto, and I want to ensure that the external device's pwr/gnd can't be tied to my pwr/gnd. NO GROUND LOOPS!

I don't need a whole lot of power - 10mA is easily enough to trigger a photodarlington like the ps2502 (or maybe something like a SI8710CC).

The parts I'm finding are in the several dollar price range. There's gotta be something like this for under a $1... can anyone suggest a part?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For isolated data *and* power on a single chip, see the Analog Devices [isoPower iCoupler](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/overviews/isoPower.pdf) parts range.

These ICs provide *"Signal and Power Transfer Across Isolation 
Barrier Using Microtransformers"* - in other words, there are integrated solid-state transformers on the die of the IC, as well as oscillator-rectifier-filtering to drive power outputs with **2.5 kV isolation**.

[image: Transformer on a chip]

Dirt-cheap? Not really.

However, if you have an interesting idea, Analog Devices has been known to not only support designs with **free samples**, they also throw in their engineering expertise, with design support engineers jumping in to help you work through any kinks in your requirement.

---

*See also [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/52919/14004) for further insight into the iCoupler product line.*

*I am not associated with Analog Devices in any way.*

Answer (score 0):

Alternative suggestion : bring out C,E from your schematic on one socket, into which you can plug the pushbutton (non-isolated) and A(via resistor R),K on a second socket as an isolated interface for external devices. These will provide their own power.

Ensure the two sockets cannot be accidentally confused : use incompatible types...

This avoids the need for an isolated supply.